# How to provide type hinting to UserDict?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I want to define a `UserDict` that reads values from JSON and stores a position for a given key. The JSON file looks like this:

```json
{
    "pages": [
        {
            "areas": [
                {
                    "name": "My_Name",
                    "x": 179.95495495495493,
                    "y": 117.92792792792793,
                    "height": 15.315315315315303,
                    "width": 125.58558558558553
                },
                ...
              ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to indicate to type linters (e.g. MyPy) that this dictionary as a key being a string and the values being a `Position`.

My current code is the following:

```py
import json
from collections import UserDict
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Dict, List, Optional, Union

from typing_extensions import Literal


JsonPosition = Dict[str, Union[str, float]]
JsonPage = Optional[Dict[Literal["areas"], List[JsonPosition]]]


@dataclass
class Position:
    """Information for a position"""

    name: str
    x: float
    y: float
    width: float
    height: float

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, dict_values: JsonPosition):
        return cls(**dict_values)  # type: ignore  # dynamic typing


class Page(UserDict):
    """Information about positions on a page"""

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, page: JsonPage):
        """Get positions from JSON Dictionary"""
        if page is None:
            return cls()

        return cls({cast(str, p["name"]): Position.from_json(p) for p in page["areas"]})



JSON = Path("my_positions.json").read_text()
positions = json.loads(JSON)
page_1 = Page.from_json(positions["pages"][0])
```

I would like MyPy (or Pylance or whatever type hinter I use), to automatically recognize `page_1["My_Name"]` as being a `Position`.

What could I change?

Comment: maybe an ```__init__()``` can help !!??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can directly provide the type to `UserDict` with square brackets (`[...]`) like you would with a `Dict`:

```py
class Page(UserDict[str, Position]):
    ...
```

For **Python 3.6** or earlier, this will not work.

For **Python >=3.7 and <3.9**, you need [the following](https://peps.python.org/pep-0585/#implementation) to subscript `collections.UserDict` and put it in a separate block specific to type checking (with constant `TYPE_CHECKING`):

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from collections import UserDict
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    TypedUserDict = UserDict[str, Position]
else:
    TypedUserDict = UserDict


class Page(TypedUserDict):
    ...
```

For **Python 3.9+**, no additional import or trick is necessary.

Comment: this doesn't work with 3.8>>> from collections import UserDict
>>> UserDict[int, int]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
>>>

Comment: @ThomasGrainger
Indeed. I had not properly tried before. I have updated the answer accordingly. You can check code here: https://replit.com/@jfthuong/Python-3812-Typed-UserDict?v=1